# Requesting for user_friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I show a screencast showing the end to end user experience if I'm requesting for the scope user_friends?

I would like to use scope to allow my game to send and receive diamonds from friends. However, I would need to pull the data, to see which of their friends has already download the game, and to send and request diamonds to each other. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I could do so using the test app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps